# Get 'event.target.id' as String

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following script return an error:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Object Reg_8712 has no method 'indexof'
```

`Reg_8712` is the radio button id who fired the event.

The script:

```
$("input:radio").change(function (event) {            

            alert(event.target.id); // this works! it returns it as string.
            var eti =  event.target.id; // 'eti' gets the object and not the string.
            var n = eti.indexof("_"); // error! cannot indexof ('eti' is an object and not string)
            var fid = eti.substring(n);
```

How can I get the 'eti' as string?

Comment: The method name is `indexOf` (note the capital O).

Comment: mike already gave the solution but in case you need string cast : `eti = String(event.target.id)` or the uggly fast version `eti =event.target.id+''`

Answer (score 4):

In case something is indeed not a string, most simple way to convert is use the generic `.toString()` method:

```
var eti =  event.target.id.toString();
var n = eti.indexOf("_");
```

[Simple test case](http://jsfiddle.net/EPx2s/) to prove the point.

Comment: if event.target.id is null. Simpler way is to use `String(event.target.id` no?

Comment: @TecHunter not really. Consider [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EPx2s/1/): JavaScript will convert null to "null". Not a great idea. In case there's chance for nulls, custom function is best in my opinion, e.g. [this fiddle contains one](http://jsfiddle.net/EPx2s/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for `indexOf`

`string.indexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex])`

```
      alert(event.target.id); // this works! it returns it as string.
        var eti =  event.target.id.toString(); // 'eti' gets the object and not the string.
        var n = eti.indexOf("_"); // error! cannot indexof ('eti' is an object and not string)
        var fid = eti.substring(n);
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf