# cannot get event.target into a string

Tags: jquery, html

In order to identify the element on which the user is clicking, I'm trying to use the Event Object `target`.

```
$(document).click(function (e) {    
    var str = e.target.toString();
    console.log(str);
    if (str.indexOf("some class or id") >= 0) {
        //do something
    };
});
```

However `.toString()` doesn't seem to have a useful effect on `e.target`. If I do:

```
console.log(e.target);
```

I get a string which contains the beginning of the DOM element, for example `<div class="myclass">`. This is needed in order to check for the presence of a substring, for example `myclass`" or `myid`, using `indexOf`.

**My purpose here is simply to identify on which div the user is clicking, by looking into `event.target` for "`myclass`".**

Yet `indexOf` will not work here, because it will return "str is not a function".

However if I try to make it into a string, as such:

```
console.log(e.target.toString());
```

I get `[object HTMLDivElement]`. No trace of the HTML string I need.

How can I get the output of `event.target` into a string I can manipulate?

p.s Notice how this situation is remarkably similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20221028/get-event-target-id-as-string), regarding `event.target.id`: yet the proposed solutions don't work for me.

Comment: Do you want to check the element’s text content, or do you only want to see if it belongs to a specific class? If you really need the content, then innerHTML, innerText etc. would be the usual suspects.

Comment: What is your actual need ? You want to get the html code of the item clicked or do you what to identify the item with class or id? Be specific with the question.

Comment: As I wrote above, "this is needed in order to check for the presence of a substring, for example myclass" or "myid" The output of event.target seems to be just the beginning of an element anyway... Because I need to know on which div the user is clicking. I'm not interested in the innerHTML, I would just use that beginning to find the class or id I look for.

Comment: @nico The question was a little confusing but now it's all clear :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to convert it to string. Get rid of `.toString()`

Directly use its `ID` property.

```
if (e.target.id == 'myid'){
    //do something
};
```

However if you want to valdate against selector use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

> Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments.

```
if ($(e.target).is('.myclass')){
    //do something
};
```

Answer (score 2):

In e.traget you have the HTML DOM element. So that, if it has an id, you should be able to do something like

```
var str = $(e.target).attr("id"); 
if(str.indexOf("id") > -1){ //do something}
```

Comment: `attr()` is a jQuery method, which is unavailable to a DOM node; you'd need `e.target.id`, `e.target.getAttribute('id')`, or: `$(e.target).attr('id')`