# Cannot convert event.target to string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ant-design-pro

I have `event.target` which is being returned by the `onRowClick` function in the Ant Design table:

https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-colspan-rowspan

Its value is `<a>ignissimos aper</a>` and of type `object` which means it can't be stringified.

There is no `id` property on event.target so this I cannot do this:

[cannot get event.target into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41804689/cannot-get-event-target-into-a-string)

How can I convert the tag to a string?

Comment: Can you also paste your code you are using to convert it into string?

Comment: Sure, I've tried `String(event.target);` and `event.target.toString();`

Comment: did you check out `event.currentTarget` as well?

Comment: Yes, it just includes more HTML

Comment: Would be nice if you were a little more clear with your issue by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60056539/edit) your question, adding an example of the desired output and adding what you said in comments direct into the question. But, I'm thinking that maybe you are looking for `event.target.outerHTML` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need data of the row clicked use the first parameter of the onRowClick function which returns the whole row object of your datasource. But if you need the innerHtml of the clicked column you can do this:

```
const onRowClick = (record, index, event) => {
  console.log(record, index, event.target.innerHTML); // event.target.innerHTML is the innerHtml of the clicked column
};
```